# How should I address a letter to a married couple who are both doctors?

Tags: salutations

Dr. John and Dr. Jane Doe?

Drs. John and Jane Doe?

Other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many variations are possible, and some more common in social than business contexts.

For example, a wedding invitation could be addressed to "The Doctors Doe" or "Drs. John and Jane Doe".

Answer (score -3):

In traditional formal usage (in the U.K., at least), the wife of the gentleman John Doe is always styled **Mrs. John Doe**.  Her given name and other titles are not used.

So your letter should be addressed to **Dr. and Mrs. John Doe**.

[Debrett’s](http://www.debretts.com/) is considered something of an authority on such matters.

Comment: The question was about a married couple who were both doctors. While at one point in time it may not have mattered that Mrs Doe was also a doctor, it certainly does today.

Comment: You would have done well to consult Debrett's -- [They get it right](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/joint-forms-address) giving an example of "Dr John and Dr Jane Watkins"