# Addressing several doctors in a salutation

Tags: salutations

Good morning Drs Smith, Brown, and Jones, (Is this correct?)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You will likely find your answer in *[Salutation for two doctors (not married)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/157777)* or *[Say thank you to multiple professors and doctors](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480918)*, or possibly *[How should I address a letter to a married couple who are both doctors?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7790)*. How you address someone is largely a matter of etiquette and protocol, not of grammar, but *Drs.* or *Drs* would indeed be a conventional way of shortening *Dr[.] Smith, Dr[.] Brown[,] and Dr[.] Jones* in a letter.